# javax.media.NoPlayerException: Cannot find a Player for wav files in jar

Tags: java, jar, jmf

I use Java Media Framework 2.1.1 for playing sounds in my application. It works fine from IDE but once I make jar package. The `Player` objects cannot be initialized with exception:

```
javax.media.NoPlayerException: Cannot find a Player for :jar:file:...
```

I create players using  `javax.media.Manager.createPlayer(URL sourceURL)`  method. I suspect that the URL from jar is causing the problems.
Is there an alternative way how to construct the player with files from jar?

Code:

```
   public SoundPlayer() {
         urlExplosion = ResourceLoader.getInstance().getSoundResourceUrl(SoundResource.EXPLOSION);
         urlTick = ResourceLoader.getInstance().getSoundResourceUrl(SoundResource.TICK);
         urlWin = ResourceLoader.getInstance().getSoundResourceUrl(SoundResource.WIN);


    }

    public void initialize() throws ResourceLoadingException{
        try {
            explosionPlayer = Manager.createPlayer(urlExplosion);
            explosionPlayer.realize();
            tickPlayer = Manager.createPlayer(urlTick);
            tickPlayer.realize();
            winPlayer = Manager.createPlayer(urlWin);
            winPlayer.realize();

        } catch (NoPlayerException e) {
            throw new ResourceLoadingException("Could not initialize the sound player",e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ResourceLoadingException("Could not initialize the sound player",e);
        }

        isInitialized = true;
    }
```

Note: the URLs are no null during runtime.

Error when run from command line: `java -jar minesweeper.jar`

```
Caused by: javax.media.NoPlayerException: Cannot find a Player for :jar:file:/path/to/app/minesweeper.jar!/my/package/minesweeper/gui/explosion.wav
```

Comment: A little more information expected. The info you provided is not enough. Provide the code where you are creating the player and the URL source url. Provide the complete line of the javax.media.NoPlayerException: Cannot.................

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).